# Two navbars boostrap 3, only one collapsing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm doing a site with Bootstrap 3, but i need 2 navigation menus, one that shows the language, contact and login and the other sections of the page.

This is the desktop view
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

and I want the language/contact/login menu to view tablet/mobile continue to show the same and that alone is the collapse menu sections.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

I added some styles and view mobile looks good but desktop view, menu sections shown aligned to the left and want it to be right-aligned, without affecting the mobile view.

The `[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/karlamip/2yqmt2kv/)`

If anyone has an idea, i was so thankful

Comment: Post your relevant code in the question. Don't try to circumvent the large warning about posting code only in an outside link. It prevent link rot for future users.

Comment: sorry :( i don't know how to do it, the warning always appear and thats the only way didn't do.

Comment: See this for adding code [Snippets](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) and it isn't very clear what you're trying to do: you both the top and bottom to collapse into one navbar or you want them to remain separated but with the collapse button in a different place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to fix the alignment, add a media query in your CSS to set the right align of those menu elements on a certain screen size (the mobile/desktop threshold).

Answer (score 0):

Just try to change `.navbar-ex1-collapse` and `data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse"` to a new class name for another menu so that it may work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the collapse menu to appear to the right of "Language / Contact Us / Login" while keeping THAT menu fixed, you need to change the position of your button collapse in your HTML structure, and alter a few classes so that there aren't conflicts.

A fork for your JSFiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/sq8u45qq/1/

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Desplegar navegación</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

The above was moved into the same row as your fixed navigation.  Then you have to remove the `collapse` for that navigation (which you seem to not want to collapse anyway) and remove the class name `navbar-ex1-collapse` which you were applying to both navigations.